# How can you convert a list of octal digits to an integer in Python using reduce()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, octal

Recently, the `reduce()` function was introduced as part of my lecture. We were given the task to write a function that takes a list of octal digits as its argument, and using the `reduce()` function, returns the `int` value of the number represented by those digits, e.g. the assert

```
assert function([6, 4, 4]) == 420
```

should return True.

I know that to convert an `oct` to an `int`, you have to do `oct * 8**n`, where `n` is the position of the value. e.g. in the given list, it'd be `6 * 8**2 + 4 * 8**1 + 4 * 8**0`.

However, I'm not quite sure how to implement this, especially since `reduce()` only takes a function that needs two variables, and applies them on each value in an iterable.

I tried a few things, involving `index()` and `len()` of the list you give to the function, but all came out wrong. They'd give far too high values, or ended up not using the second variable required by `reduce()` at all.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lambda x, y: 8*x+y` as function in [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

def function(l):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: 8*x+y, l)

assert function([6, 4, 4]) == 420
```

Breaking down the steps:

```
 x=6, y=4:  8*6 + 4 =  52
x=52, y=4: 8*52 + 4 = 420
```

Comment: Huh, I guess i just completely misunderstood what the reduce() function did, then... but this worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: @c.d. did you understand it now?

Comment: I do believe so, yes.